# MVVM Room -> DAO -> Repository -> ViewModel -> Activity using lists and background thread

Tags: android, mvvm, repository-pattern, dao, android-livedata

I have struggled with implementing this for a while, I have watched many tutorials but they always show the basic examples and never seem to take into account these data structures and threading.

I am sure developers do this every day so it should be easy for someone to show me.

The problem:

I have my Room database imagine I have a list of datatype 'Level'. I want to be able to observe the allLevels List. currently the architecture is I have a levelDAO

```
public interface LevelDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Level... Levels);
    @Update
    void update(Level... Levels);
    @Delete
    void delete(Level... Levels);

    //Live Data
    //Get All Live Levels
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Level")
    MutableLiveData<List<Level>> selectLiveAllLevels();


}
```

I then have a Level Repository

```
public class LevelRepository {

    private LevelDao levelDao;
    private MutableLiveData<List<Level>> allLevels;

    public LevelRepository(Application application){
        WayMapDatabase wayMapDatabase = WayMapDatabase.getInstance(application);
        levelDao = wayMapDatabase.levelDao();
        allLevels = levelDao.selectLiveAllLevels();
    }

    public void insert(Level level){
        new InsertLevelAsyncTask(levelDao).execute(level);
    }
    public void update(Level level){
        new UpdateLevelAsyncTask(levelDao).execute(level);
    }
    public void delete(Level level){
        new DeleteLevelAsyncTask(levelDao).execute(level);
    }

    //Live Data
    public MutableLiveData<List<Level>> getLiveAllLevels(){
        return allLevels;
    }

    //Async Tasks
    private static class InsertLevelAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Level, Void, Void> {

        private LevelDao levelDao;
        private InsertLevelAsyncTask(LevelDao levelDao){
            this.levelDao = levelDao;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Level... levels) {
            levelDao.insert(levels[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class UpdateLevelAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Level, Void, Void> {

        private LevelDao levelDao;
        private UpdateLevelAsyncTask(LevelDao levelDao){
            this.levelDao = levelDao;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Level... levels) {
            levelDao.update(levels[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteLevelAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Level, Void, Void> {

        private LevelDao levelDao;
        private DeleteLevelAsyncTask(LevelDao levelDao){
            this.levelDao = levelDao;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Level... levels) {
            levelDao.delete(levels[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Which as you can see following tutorials showed me how to put the basic insert, update, delete on to a background thread (I think). However the getLiveLevels() is not, and I assume this will never work as we have to connect to the database on a background thread?

I then have my ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    //Test
    private LevelRepository levelRepository;
    private MutableLiveData<List<Level>> allLevels;
    //Test

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        //Test
        levelRepository = new LevelRepository(application);
        allLevels = levelRepository.getLiveAllLevels();
        //Test
    }

    public LiveData<List<Level>> getAllLevels(){
        if(allLevels == null){
            allLevels = levelRepository.getLiveAllLevels();
        }
        return allLevels;
    }
}
```

I then go on to observe the viewModel Object in my activity, but this never seems to work the list never gets updated I do not get errors just does no updates to the list so its pretty frustrating.

I observe in the activity as below:

```
mainViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        mainViewModel.getAllLevels().observe(this, new Observer<List<Level>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Level> levels) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged:  changed; "+ levels.size());
            }
        });
```

It would be really helpful if someone would show me the DAO, Repository, ViewModel, Activity implementation which would work for this implementation so i can replicate it over my other room interactions, including making sure it works as should on background thread and for the Livedata Lists.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution, I thought this would be a very common implementation?

Comment: Setting up Room takes some practice, I would suggest going through the 'Android Room with a View' code lab it was updated just over a month ago.https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#0
This code lab should answer all your questions.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the tip, However the example again does not take care of any threading, there are comments saying conflicting things such as: // Room executes all queries on a separate thread. and the 3 lines later // You must call this on a non-UI thread or your app will throw an exception. is there not a way of taking care of the threading in the dao level so i do not have to think about this when calling for this Data? Do these comment mean that any query involving LiveData i do not have to worry about threading at all?

Answer (score 0):

When using Room all queries are handled on a separate thread, this is one of the advantages of using Room.

[image]

This screenshot is taken from the code lab. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#8